# How to download RawResults.zip via rest api from hp alm

Tags: rest, download, alm

I need to download RawResults.ip via rest from HP ALM. I read more info about this question, but i didn`t see any worked solutions... I tried to download zip archive from browser via rest and used links like this:

```
http://{server:port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/results/{file-id}/logical-storage/
```

but always i had error message: `Access to this resource has been denied.` Can someone tell me way to download this file via rest? HP ALM version is 12.20

Comment: I think you need to authorize first, otherwise you will always get 403 code

Comment: Always i authorize first. Also i used AuthenticateLoginLogoutExample from here https://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.50/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html and tried to download RawResults.zip from this link `http://{server:port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/results/{file-id}/logical-storage/` and i had same error message...

Comment: Are you able to get any other resource after authorization?

Comment: Yes, i can get, for example, xml with RawResults.zip id from last launched test.

Comment: i solved my problem, java example from here https://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.50/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html returns 401 html code on authentication. I try to write code like example on python and it`s working.